# HP Dv6000 Overheating Issue?

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, fan, cooling

I have been using a HP dv6000 laptop for quite some time (months if not years), without any problems. I recently purchased a replacement fan for the motherboard, because the bearings in the existing one had been playing up for months (loud noise if the fan reached a certain speed).

Recently it got so bad that whenever the fan became very noisy, I had no alternative but to shutdown the laptop and restart it again.

I came to do the replacement last night. Unscrewed the existing one, and compared the two, to make sure that it was the same.  Now, before you say anything, I am fully aware of a common NVidia fault with these models of HP laptop, but mine has NEVER given me ANY such problems.

BOTH the original and replacements have light blue pads on them.  Before I replaced the fan, I applied some thermal paste on top of the CPU, and fixed the new fan to the board, put everything back together again, and restarted the laptop.  The new fan did seem to be coming on quite regularly, but the original one might have being doing the same (I can't remember).

Anyway, got booted up into Windows, but as soon as I went to watch TV online, the screen went off and the laptop shutdown.  I tried restarting the laptop, but this time, it got as far as the Windows logo, then shutdown.

It was getting late, so I left it for the night and then started again this morning, but also did a bit of research online to see if I could find the possible cause of the problem.  I should also point out that before I left the laptop for the night last night, the laptop WILL run fine if you just go into the BIOS.

This morning the only thing I've done differently is remove the thermal paste between the blue pad and the CPU, because I've read that you should NEVER do that.

At the moment, the laptop has been sat for at least an hour just on the BIOS screen without problems (and I can hear the fan going, but it's not loud).
I am semi frightened to try booting up Windows in case it does the same thing again, but obviously will have to eventually.

Could the fact that I applied thermal paste between the blue pad and the CPU have reduced the cooling efficiency of the fan and heatsink?

Something else I should make clear is that when I took the original fan off, there was NO SIGN WHATSOEVER of any thermal paste on EITHER the Nvidia GPU or the CPU, so I'm guessing it can't possibly be related to a lack of thermal paste, because it's been like that for yonks WITHOUT issue.

@Jonno - Thank you for your second response.  An update for you.  I plucked up the courage to test it again.  It booted up successfully to Windows and I deliberately left it on the Desktop for hours, still fine.  The only thing I've done so far is open up Windows Explorer on it, to get access to all my files (which I am going to get a backup of).  The fan does keep coming on now and again, but apart from that, nothing.  I'm unfortunately not going to try and watch TV on it at the moment, because it went off at that stage.  I am wondering if the reason why it shut down at the windows startup logo before, is maybe because it was still too hot perhaps?  I also managed to find information on the known Nvidia fault going back to 2007, which I understand a lawsuit was started against them apparently, because it affected certain Dell models as well?

Comment: I have updated my answer with some responses to your other questions.

Answer (score 0):

As you've stated, and you're not going to like my answer I don't think, there is a common fault with these laptops, and about 6 years ago at a computer shop I worked at we would see these very frequently. The machine model actually had an official recall, and it was caused by the graphics chip overheating.

We did offer our customers a fairly non-recommended 'fix', which involved overheating the chip and effectively "reballing" it, which potentially gave the machine a bit more life, but inevitably they would die again and we offered absolutely no guarantee anything would be resolved. I don't recommend you do this, but we saw a large percentage of them come back to life, if only temporarily. Most of these cases wouldn't go to the BIOS screen like yours seems to be, but would turn on and sit on a black screen for a very long time.

The thermal paste shouldn't have caused too much of an issue, although not recommended, it is heat conductive and shouldn't have made a problem (depending on how much you used). The rubber pad likely absorbs more heat than the paste would have.

Honestly, it's hard to recommend a solution, as the laptop does have this fault and, whether it's coincidence or causation, it has occurred now. You can try booting to Windows, you're unlikely to do any further harm as such. Really though, I think the laptop has served you well not to fail after this long.

Try and boot to Windows, if it still works, great. If it doesn't, like I say, off the record we used to force these machines to overheat with the screen off, but I don't recommend you do this at all and the risks outweigh the possible positives. I'd cut my losses and look into a replacement.

To answer your questions from your answer:

Actually, the BIOS probably generates a lot more heat than usual, as it rarely has any power save functionality, especially for the GPU. As such it usually doesn't downclock or undervolt, although it wouldn't be running at a particularly high load.

It does seem *very* coincidental to the point it does seem relevant. Really it's almost impossible to know, and I can't really suggest anything. Perhaps it didn't cool quite as efficiently as the previous fan, I just don't know. I'd see if it boots up, if so make sure all your backups are up to date and prepare for the worst.